# Does iPhone 5 support MetalPerformanceShaders framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, ios10, ios-frameworks

Im wondering if iPhone 5 supports the `MetalPerformanceShaders` framework. If not, what is the alternative that I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metal requires a 64-bit CPU, so no. More details can be found in this [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW13).

Comment: Just linking to an answer is generally not considered to be good etiquette. You might want to answer the question and provide the link for further reading?

Comment: I was just frustrated that nobody was answering my question. @StephenDarlington

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question. It happens if you ask a hard or obscure one!